# Error when using eGARCH but not sGARCH in rugarch

Tags: r, time-series, garch, error-message, volatility

I have implemented the basic sGarch model using the code below:

```r
spec <- ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH", garchOrder = c(1, 1)), 
                   mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(1, 1)), 
                   distribution.model = "norm")
ARMA_GARCH.models <- list()
  
for (i in 1 : length(vol)) {
  ARMA_GARCH.models[[i]] <- ugarchfit(spec = spec, data = log_r1[[i]] %>% 
                                        filter(time <= 480) %>% pull(log_return),
                                      solver = 'hybrid')
}
```

**However, my issue is that when I change the model to eGARCH**, I get the error `"Error in as.xts(log_r1[, -1], order.by = log_r1$time) : could not find function "as.xts".`

If I could get some view as to why this error is occurring, I would highly appreciate it. Thanks!